# How to force the form to search within a specific site only via Google Search

Tags: html, forms, google-search

I have a simple search form that I want redirected to the Google Search page to search for the input when the button is clicked. The code below works:

```
<form role='search' method='get' action='http://www.google.com/search'>
  <input type='search' name='q' />
  <button type='search' value='search'>Search</button>
</form>
```

However, I want to search only for a specific website. I tried modifying the  `name='q'` code below to search within w3schools only (adding `site:w3schools.com`), but the site-specific search doesn't work:

```
<input type='search' name='q=site%3Aw3schools.com' />
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
   <input type="hidden" name="q" value="site:http://yoursite.com">
   <input type="text" name="q" alt="search">
   <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Google ignores the site in the search results.

Comment: It's working for me, maybe there is an error in something esle

Comment: Yes, it indeed works. Sorry. I traced the error with an old (and unused) JavaScript code within my document: `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("input, textarea"),function(a){a.value=""});`.

Comment: @SergioRivas, how in the world do I get this to work with DuckDuckGo? I have `<form action="https://duckduckgo.com" method="get" target="_blank">`, but I can't get it to work the same as in the Google example in your answer.

Comment: @JoelDeWitt I added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70946764/13765033) to the question that also works for DuckDuckGo.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, it is possible to perform the search via JavaScript. This method also works for search engines that doesn't combine multiple GET parameters automatically, as Google does it.

### Google

When searching on Google like [this](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Adavid.wolf.gdn&q=software%20development):

```
https://google.com/search?q=site%3Adavid.wolf.gdn
                         &q=software+development
```

Google automatically combines both GET parameters with the name `q` into one and in the search bar appears a value of:

```
site:david.wolf.gdn software development
```

### DuckDuckGo

While when searching on DuckDuckGo, for example, like [this](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Adavid.wolf.gdn&q=software%20development):

```
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Adavid.wolf.gdn
                       &q=software+development
```

DuckDuckGo will only use the last GET parameter with the value of `q`. The URL gets trimmed to:

```
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=software+development
```

And only a search for that query will be executed:

```
software development
```

## Solution

As a workaround for search engines that doesn't provide the described functionality of changing GET parameters and combining them into a single query, you can make use of JavaScript to build the URL and perform the redirect:

```js
;(function () {
  const form = document.querySelector("form")
  if (!form) return
  form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const input = document.querySelector('input[name="q"]')
    if (!input) return
    const query = input.value
    window.location.href = `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Adavid.wolf.gdn+${query}`
  })
})()
```

```html
<form>
  <input type=search name=q id=q placeholder="I am looking for …">
  <label for=q>
        Press enter to search
  </label>
</form>
```

In the above code, replace `david.wolf.gdn` with your desired domain name to limit the search results to.

#### Startpage

The same works for startpage.com, use this search engine URL:

```plain
https://www.startpage.com/sp/search?query=site%3Aindex.garden+${query}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [Google Programmable Search Engine](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview). Google supports a way to power site search on your site with Google.  There are several advantages to trying to modify the default Google search form:

1. It can be limited to a single site or group of sites.
2. You can change the look and feel of the search results page with your custom colors and logo.
3. You can get a share of the advertising revenue from the search results.